# .NET 5 + Custom appsettings.json - The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page

Tags: c#, json, reactjs, .net-5

I have a C# .NET5 Project with ReactJS (VS Project Template for C# projects).

If I do not change **appsettings.json** and **launchSettings.json** everything works fine (localhost DEV and also TEST server where I send app by Publish).

In ASP.NET MVC5 (.NET Framework) I use Publish button and after switch Debug or Release I had web.config with the same suffix as web.Release.config, and in this file I had configuration for Release DB.

Now in **.NET 5** I would like to have more **appsettings** file with diff configuration (Home, Work, Contractor, Test, Prod), for only switch config name (Run Name in VS) which is defined and connected with **launchSettings.json**, now I must on diff PC comment ConnectionString for selected DB on machine

And I like to have also for **Publish** button in main runnable project load only **appsettings.Prod.json** to Production server

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();

        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\AuditInfo-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day", // Rolling Interval
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} [{Level}] ({ThreadId}) - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]

  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=home;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;"
    //"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;"
    //"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=work;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;"
    //"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=contractor;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53806",
      "sslPort": 44348
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Search": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have these **appsettings.___.json** file by default

[image]

If I add new **appsettings.Dev.json** and edit **launchSettings.json** like:

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53806",
      "sslPort": 44348
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Dev": { // NEW RUN option with connect to Dev appsettings file
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Dev"
      }
    },
    "Test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Dev.json**

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=dev;Initial Catalog=dev;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

I got only HTTP 500 Response and in log I got this **error**:

```
02.04.2021 19:27:57 [Error] (6) - An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

---

The main problem is in **Startup.cs** in **env.IsDevelopment()** if I comment condition, everything works fine (for Dev I use IISExpress):

```
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            //}
        });
```

Is it possible to register another **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** variable then Development and Use it with function **env.IsDevelopment()** ? Or is there another way how to do it ?

Comment: Is your new setting file set to copy to output directory? Have you verified it exists?

Comment: Yes, all file was in build dir (bin), the have set "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`env.IsDevelopment()` is `true` only when [`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is `Development`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostenvironmentenvextensions.isdevelopment). There are other options though:

1. Use `env.IsEnvironment('some_env')`
2. Write your own extension - [here is the source for env.IsDevelopment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/src/HostEnvironmentEnvExtensions.cs#L18)